# Creating a string from chars

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read input from an array into a string, but it's not working so well. Here's my code.

```
std::string str1;
//for(int i = 0; grid[0][i].letter !=0; i++)

    char ch1 = grid[0][0].letter;
    char ch2 = grid[0][1].letter;
    char ch3 = grid[0][2].letter;
    char ch4 = grid[0][3].letter;
    char ch5 = grid[0][4].letter;
    char ch6 = grid[0][5].letter;


cout << ch1 << ch2 << ch3 << ch4 << ch5 << ch6;
str1 += ch1 + ch2 + ch3 + ch4 + ch5 + ch6;
cout << str1;
```

Earlier, I had set the grid[0][x] to be equal to the chars 'e' 'g' 'g' 'c' 'a' 't', respectively. When I print all the ch chars next to each other, it displays "eggcat", as it should. However, for some reason, when I try to print out str1, which should also display "eggcat", it instead only gives me the letter 'k'. I've been trying for a while to fix this, but I haven't been able to at all. Does anyone know what the problem might be? I'm only #including iostream, iterator, and algorithm, so if I'm just forgetting to #include something, please let me know!

Comment: If you are interested in the math look at this paste bin http://pastebin.com/h8cPQs5G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding a lot of characters before applying str1 += result_of_addition.

Make it:

```
str1 = str1 + ch1 + ch2 + ch3 + ch4 + ch5 + ch6
```

An operation char + char results in char - the operation std::string + char results in a std::string. The precedence of the operator += is less than the precedence of the operator +. Hence all chars (in your example) are added before that result is added to your string.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Everything I found that related to adding chars to a string told me to use +=, which I'm not familiar with. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use a stringstream:

```
#include <sstream>

stringstream ss;
ss << ch1 << ch2 << ch3 << ch4 << ch5 << ch6;
str1 = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep appending `char`s to a `std::string`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string str;

   str += 'a';
   str += 'b';
   str += 'c';
   str += 'd';

   std::cout << str << std::endl;
};
```

Output

```
abcd
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
std::string str1;
str1.reserve( sizeof( grid[0] ) / sizeof( *grid[0] ) );

for ( const auto &cell : grid[0] ) str1.push_back( cell.letter ); 
cout << str1;
```

The above code also can be written as

```
std::string str1;
str1.reserve( sizeof( grid[0] ) / sizeof( *grid[0] ) );

for ( const auto &cell : grid[0] ) str1 += cell.letter; 
cout << str1;
```

Or even the following way

```
std::string str1;
str1.reserve( sizeof( grid[0] ) / sizeof( *grid[0] ) );

for ( char c : { grid[0][0].letter, grid[0][1].letter, grid[0][2].letter, 
                 grid[0][3].letter, grid[0][4].letter, grid[0][5].letter  } )
{
    str1 += c;
}

cout << str1;
```

Or you could use standard algorithm `std::transform` for example

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::string str1;
str1.reserve( sizeof( grid[0] ) / sizeof( *grid[0] ) );

std::transform( std::begin( grid[0] ), std::end( grid[0] ), std::back_inserter( str1 ),
                []( decltype( *grid[0] ) &cell ) { return cell.letter; } );
```